# Magento 2 Insert Data into custom table using Collection Factory

Tags: magento2

I am following tutorials at http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_crud_models_for_database_access/ for creating my extension but theres one key part of that tutorial that appears to be out of date.

This Part :

```
$todo = $this->toDoFactory->create();
$todo->setData('item_text','Finish my Magento article')
->save();
```

SetData and Save no longer work this way.

So how can I use a Collection Factory to create a new item in my table?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I figured it out.

First you would do $this->toDoFactory->create()**->getNewEmptyItem()**; And then continue on with setting data and saving.